# Is it possible to verify `showDialog` was called in flutter unit tests?

Tags: flutter

I want to write a unit test that verifies an `AlertDialog` in my flutter app is configured to close if you tap outside of it, i.e, the `barrierDismissible` parameter is set to `true` when calling `showDialog()`.

AFAIK, it should be possible to unit-test this functionality indirectly by tapping a part of the screen that I expect to be outside the `AlertDialog`. For example:

```dart
    testWidgets('tapping outside the alert dialog closes it', (tester) async {
      when(() => cubit.state).thenReturn(loadedState.copyWith(complete: true));
      await tester.pumpWidget(QuizBodyFixture(quizCubit: cubit));

      await tester.tap(find.byKey(QuizKeys.abortButton));

      await tester.pumpAndSettle();

      final finder = find.byKey(QuizKeys.abortDialog);
      expect(finder, findsOneWidget);

      await tester.tapAt(const Offset(1, 1));
      expect(finder, findsNothing);
    });
```

But since the underlying platform guarantees this behavior through the `barrierDismissible` parameter when calling `showDialog()`, I would rather test that my implementation simply passes that parameter.

Is it possible to write such a unit test?